# Selecting a range of cells based on a loop variable

Tags: vba

I've tried for days to find an answer to this but honestly, it might be a lack of knowledge in the subject that's causing me to not search for the right terms.

I have a spreadsheet with a series of dates between S7:GE7 and rows from 8:96 that have data that need to be locked the next day.

I know my way of selecting the columns is all wrong, and there's probably more wrong too but I can't think of a way to make it right.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Range, cell As Range
Set i = Range("S7:GE7")

For Each cell In i
      If (cell.Value < DateValue(Now())) Then
          Range(i + "8:96").Locked = True
      End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

What I'm hoping to achieve with this is a loop that looks through the dates in S7:GE7, and if the date is older than today it locks cells 8:96 in that column.

Any help that can be provided would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i As Range, cell As Range
Set i = Range("S7:GE7")

For Each cell In i
      If (cell.Value < DateValue(Now())) Then

          cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(79, 1).Locked = True

        End If
Next cell

End Sub
```